# how to use on_hot for combined text and number

Tags: keras, one-hot-encoding

I am using keras and I want to train a model to recognize texts. however, within my text I have numbers as well. and of course since there is a number within text on_hot does not know what to do with it and I get this error :

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'translate'

any idea what should I do? 
I have text like:
'9145 > 23 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your error. The numbers are strings when one_hot is called. To show you I called text_to_word_sequence.

```
In [8]: from keras.preprocessing import text as kt

In [9]: text = '9145 > 23 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=12713 Len=0 [ETHERNET FRAME CHECK SEQUENCE INCORRECT]'

In [10]: kt.text_to_word_sequence(text)
Out[10]: 
['9145',
 '23',
 'syn',
 'seq',
 '0',
 'win',
 '12713',
 'len',
 '0',
 'ethernet',
 'frame',
 'check',
 'sequence',
 'incorrect']

In [11]: kt.one_hot(text, 20)
Out[11]: [12, 3, 9, 4, 5, 18, 12, 2, 5, 1, 13, 12, 16, 17]
```

Comment: ah you are correct, it was nan value which was causing it to blow up. Many many thanks for your help.